# Once I upload a file using multer, how do I send it back to the front-end?

Tags: reactjs, express, filesystems

Basically, I've read that people use a filesystem to save a file to the server, and then save the file's path to the database... Rather than save the file itself on the database.

From my understanding, the Express library Multer creates the filesystem.

I've attempted to just upload a file using multer and send the path back to the front-end, however, this doesn't seem to work.

Back-end code

```
app.post("/upload", cpUpload, (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("app.post /upload");
    console.log(req.file.path); 

    const host = req.hostname;
    const filePath = req.protocol + "://" + host + '/' + req.file.path;
    console.log(host); 
    res.send({msg:filePath});

});
```

The message that gets sent back is

```
http://localhost/uploads/f03401055620d23e71b0d5351d477c7e
```

however, I end up getting "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: Create an endpoint `uploads/:fileName` that sends the file

Comment: What port is your server running on? http://localhost defaults to port 80. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED means you are trying to hit port 80 but nothing is listening there.